# jquery form submission (non-AJAX) callback not working

Tags: jquery, submit

I need to submit my form with an external button as follows and need to redirect the page after submit is success. The code below does not work and I am not using any AJAX for this.

```
// CODE 1: THIS DOES NOT WORK
$("#myButton").click(function(){ 

   $("#myForm").submit(function(){
        window.location.href = "test.jsp";
   });  
});
```

However, if I use some time delay as follow, it works:

```
// CODE 2: THIS WORKS
$("#myButton").click(function(){ 
    $("#myForm").submit();
    setTimeout(function(){
    window.location.href = "test.jsp";
   }, 2000);
});
```

Whenever there is a delay about 2 seconds between the submit() and redirection, everything works. But, I can not use the timer here and form submit call back is not working.

Can anyone tell me how can I solve it?

Comment: in your first code, you are setting submit handler without firing it

Comment: your first code logically doesn't make sense, if you intended for it to perform a submit.

Comment: any idea what the code should be like?